# How can i fix the position of Spotlight as its getting disturbed while scrolling using React-joyride library?

Tags: reactjs

[spotlight issue while scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8WNG.png).

I have been trying to find out the solution for the above position issue while using React-joyride for creating a tour for the website.

Can someone help me in providing guidance on how to fix the above problem?

Thanks

I did go through the link below but i could not really understand if there is a fix:-
(https://github.com/gilbarbara/react-joyride/issues/376)

Answer (score 0):

Set position of element to fixed so that it always remain there as it is!

Comment: Hi I tried using the below snippet in react joyride:-
 <JoyRide 
...
styles={{
...
spotlight:{
             // boxShadow: '0px 0px 0px 9999px rgba(0,154,223,0.9)',
              position: 'fixed' 
             }
}}

It did not work. I tried some other position properties but no luck.